# How can I change response xml in JAX-WS

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I have the following XML as my JAX-WS web service response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <QueryRBTReqMsgResponse>
            <QueryRBTRspMsg>
                <resultHeader>
                    <resultCode>0</resultCode>
                    <resultDesc>Successful</resultDesc>
                </resultHeader>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <QueryRBTResponse>
                    <part>1</part>
                </QueryRBTResponse>
            </QueryRBTRspMsg>
        </QueryRBTReqMsgResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But this is what I want:

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <QueryRBTRspMsg>
            <resultHeader>
                <resultCode>0</resultCode>
                <resultDesc>Successful</resultDesc>
            </resultHeader>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <QueryRBTResponse>
                <part>1</part>
            </QueryRBTResponse>
        </QueryRBTRspMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I remove the `<QueryRBTReqMsgResponse>` tag from my response? I tried too many changes but none of them did the job!!!

Comment: How do you generate this response? How does the response POJO of your service look like? I am guessing it has QueryRBTReqMsgResponse as root element.

Comment: This response generated by standard Jax-Ws java library and there is no Pojo.

Comment: This is the response of a SOAP service somewhere. JAX-WS is just an API.  Did you build the service that returns this response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. We have to use following annotation:

```
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
```